# OscillatorStrength[Helium] and OscillatorStrength[Rubidium] do not return results

Tags: packages, physics, curated-data, chemistry

I am new to working with the [Resonance Absorption Lines Pacgage](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ResonanceAbsorptionLines/tutorial/ResonanceAbsorptionLines.html)

```
<< ResonanceAbsorptionLines`
```

and trying to write code using the [OscillatorStrength](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ResonanceAbsorptionLines/ref/OscillatorStrength.html) command. While I get nice results for many elements ie:

```
OscillatorStrength[Hydrogen]
OscillatorStrength[Lithium]
OscillatorStrength[Beryllium]
OscillatorStrength[Carbon]
```

Some elements such as

```
OscillatorStrength[Helium]
OscillatorStrength[Rubidium]
```

return empty sets.
Is this a bug in the package or a bug in my understanding?

Comment: This looks like a very old package, only has information on 32 elements.  Have you looked at [`SpectralLineData`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SpectralLineData.html)?

Comment: @JasonB. I have looked at SpectralLineData and am in fact using it for other calculations within this same code, but I have been unable to get the oscillator strengths directly from this package.